# ifelse get value from respective column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The idea behind the question is to get something like this:

```
data['output'] = np.where(data['column']=='Z', 0, 1)
```

But in my case what I really need is not a specific 0 or 1 value, is a value from another column such as:

```
data['output'] = np.where(data['column']=='Z', data['col1'], data['col2'])
```

Not sure if this is possible like this

Comment: Not sure if understand problem, second solution is also correct like first one.

Comment: second solution actually works? Does it get the right row matching?

Comment: No, because mask and assigned columns has same length (because same DataFrame) `np.where` return numpy array with same length like `df`, so adding new column working nice.

Comment: Ok I tested and it works.. Never thought it would.. I can just edit the question removing the second solution and you can post an answer for the question which is basically that second post, if you find useful. Otherwise I just delete it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
choices = [data['col1'], data['col2']]
    
    
data['output'] = np.choose(np.where(data['column']=='Z', 0, 1), choices)
```

Comment: Please provide some context to your suggestion, so others could learn from it. Please consider to check [answer]